# Checksum algorithm for SQL query?

Tags: algorithm, md5, sha, crc32

I need to generate a checksum based on a SQL query and the string values of any parameters used in that query. The checksum is used in a caching scenario. If the checksum exists in cache, so does the result and then I don't need to hit the DB.

Req 1:
It's important that two different queries doesn't generate the same hash. Because that could lead to an unexpected result being returned.

Req 2:
It can't be tremendously slow, but again it's in memory and shouldn't have to much content.

Given the context, what algorithm is best fit? CRC32, MD5, SHA1 or anything else?

//Daniel

Comment: this question is basically an popularity poll and therefore not fit for SO QA format. Try to rephrase it in a way that makes a simple, to the point answer possible. Also, in my opinion, its always better to ask for what you want done, not for the tools you think are necessary for the task. In this case, you should ask for query result cashing on the application side (im guessing you want to limit network traffic). Otherwise, you could be asking for a knife to screw in some screws, while someone could have offered you an electric screwdriver.

Comment: "it's kind of important that two different queries doesn't generate the same hash" - that's unfortunate.

Comment: 1) parse the query 2) transform the parse tree into a canonical form 3) serialise the tree into a (canonical) string 4) use the resulting string as a key, or use it as the input for a 5) hashfunction

Comment: @wildplasser I do that, the question is which hash algorithm to use of the resulting string?

Comment: The choice of hashfunction is relatively unimportant, since you can keep the (canonical) querystrings and use them for a final compare to resolve collisions. If you don't intend to keep more than 64K items in the cache, any reasonable 32 bits hashfunction would suffice.

Comment: "It's important that two different queries doesn't generate the same hash. Because that could lead to an unexpected result being returned."  Then the only acceptable hash is the entire query itself or some lossless compression of the query.  Anything shorter cannot be assured to have no collisions.  If you use hashing you have to be able to properly deal with collisions, however rare they may be.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole query string concatenated with the arguments in a regular HashTable / Dictionary / HashMap or whatever it is called in your language. Put the SQL query as the key and the result as the value.

Your HashTable will use an appropriate hashing function for your strings and resolve any hash collisions.

Comment: Not sure about that. Sounds appealing but as long as I can't read up in the docs about what kind of uniqueness they guarantee, it suddenly isn't that attractive. It's like the GetHashCode implementation. It's not guaranteed to be unique....

Comment: @Daniel, yes, there is no uniqueness in the GetHashCode, but has not to be. Most HashTables store duplicate hashes in a linked list or in the next available slot. To be sure you don't get the wrong item back the whole key is compared when a hash of the key is found.

Comment: @Daniel, what language do you use?